# Limit maximum number of concurrent scp processes running on a host

Tags: process, scp, limit

I am facing a problem where I have a fleet of servers which contain a lot of data. Each of the host runs many instances of a specific process p1, which makes several scp connections to other hosts in parallel to get the data it has to process. This in turn puts a lot of load on these hosts and many times they go down.

I am looking for ways through which I can limit the number of concurrent scp processes that can be run on a single host.

Most of the links pointed me to MaxStartup & MaxSessions settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config which were more to do with limiting the number of ssh sessions that can be made/initiated at any given point etc.

Is there a specific config file for scp which can be used here? Or is there a way at the system level to limit the number of instances of a specific process/command that can run concurrently at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scp` itself has no such feature. With GNU [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) you can use the `sem` command (from [*semaphore*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)) to arbitrarily limit concurrent processes:

```
sem --id scp -j 50 scp ...
```

For all processes started with the same `--id`, this applies a limit of 50 concurrent instances. An attempt to start a 51st process will wait (indefinitely) until one of the other processes exits. Add `--fg` to keep the process in the foreground (default is to run it in the background, but this doesn't behave quite the same a shell background process).

Note that the state is stored in `${HOME}/.parallel/` so this won't work quite as hoped if you have multiple users using `scp`, you may need a lower limit for each user. (It should also be possible override the `HOME` environment variable when invoking `sem`, make sure `umask` permits group write, and modify the permissions so they share state, I have not tested this heavily though, YMMV.)

`parallel` requires only `perl` and a few standard modules.

You might also consider using `scp -l N` where N is a transfer limit in kBps, select a specific cipher (for speed, depending on your required security), or disable compression (especially if the data is already compressed) to further reduce CPU impact.

For `scp`, ssh is effectively a pipe and an `scp` instance runs on each end (the receiving end runs with the undocumented `-t` option). Regarding `MaxSessions`, this won't help, "sessions" are multiplexed over a single SSH connection. Despite copious misinformation to the contrary, `MaxSessions` limits *only* the multiplexing of sessions per-TCP connection, not any other limit.

The PAM module [`pam_limits`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_limits.html) supports limiting concurrent logins, so if OpenSSH is built with PAM, and `usePAM yes` is present in the `sshd_config` you can set limit by username, group membership (and more). You can then set a hard `maxlogins` to limit the logins in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. *However* this counts up all logins per user, not just the new logins using just `ssh`, and not just `scp`, so you might run into trouble unless you have a dedicated `scp` user id. Once enabled, it will also apply to interactive ssh sessions. One way around this is to copy or symlink the `sshd` binary, calling it `sshd-scp` then you can use a separate PAM configuration file, i.e. `/etc/pam.d/sshd-scp` (OpenSSH calls `pam_start()` with the "service name" set to that of the binary it was invoked as). You'll need to run this on a separate port (or IP), and using a separate `sshd_config` is probably a good idea too.
If you implement this, then `scp` will fail (exit code 254) when the limit is reached, so you'll have to deal with that in your transfer process.

(Other options include [`ionice`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html) and [`cpulimit`](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/), these may cause `scp` sessions to timeout or hang for long periods, causing more problems.)

The old school way of doing something similar is to use `atd` and `batch`, but that doesn't offer tuning of concurrency, it queues and starts processes when the load is below a specific threshold. A newer variation on that is [*Task Spooler*](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/) that supports queueing and running jobs in a more configurable sequential/parallel way, with runtime reconfiguration supported (e.g. changing queued jobs and concurrency settings), though it offers no load or CPU related control itself.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this indeed is helpful. There other thing I wanted to ask can we limit the number of 'scp' processes using MaxSessions limit in sshd_config file? From what I understand is that SCP uses SSH connection for file transfer so a hard limit on number of MaxSessions for SSH connections should indirectly limit the number of SCP processes that can run on a host. Though I am not sure.

Comment: Updated. `MaxSessions` limits "sessions" which are multiplexed over a single SSH connection, it won't help...